# Configuring org-msg to use Lualatex in emails

Tags: org-mode, mu4e

I'm using Lualatex with a custom package and have org-mode configured to it using

```
(setq org-latex-compiler "lualatex")
```

I also put all the Latex-packages I usually need into a custom one and configured org-mode to use that when compiling. This works great, except when I want to send emails with mu4e that include Latex-equations, in which case I get an error message:

```
org-compile-file: File "/tmp/orgtex32228nYH.pdf" wasn't produced.  Please adjust 'imagemagick' part of `org-preview-latex-process-alist'.
```

Inspecting the compilation logs shows that the compilation ends because Emacs tries to compile the file using Latex, not Lualatex. So I tried to change `org-preview-latex-process-alist` to use Lualatex. After some unsuccessful partial reconfiguration attempts, I replaced pretty much all `latex`-values `lualatex`:

```
(setq org-preview-latex-process-alist
      '((luamagick :programs
        ("lualatex" "convert")
        :description "pdf > png" :message "you need to install lualatex and imagemagick." :use-xcolor t :image-input-type "pdf" :image-output-type "png" :image-size-adjust
        (1.0 . 1.0)
        :latex-compiler
        ("lualatex -interaction nonstopmode -output-directory %o %f")
        :image-converter
        ("convert -density %D -trim -antialias %f -quality 100 %O"))
 (dvipng :programs
     ("lualatex" "dvipng")
     :description "dvi > png" :message "you need to install the programs: latex and dvipng." :image-input-type "dvi" :image-output-type "png" :image-size-adjust
     (1.0 . 1.0)
     :latex-compiler
     ("lualatex -interaction nonstopmode -output-directory %o %f")
     :image-converter
     ("dvipng -D %D -T tight -bg Transparent -o %O %f"))
 (dvisvgm :programs
      ("lualatex" "dvisvgm")
      :description "dvi > svg" :message "you need to install the programs: latex and dvisvgm." :image-input-type "dvi" :image-output-type "svg" :image-size-adjust
      (1.7 . 1.5)
      :latex-compiler
      ("lualatex -interaction nonstopmode -output-directory %o %f")
      :image-converter
      ("dvisvgm %f -n -b min -c %S -o %O"))
 (imagemagick :programs
          ("lualatex" "convert")
          :description "pdf > png" :message "you need to install the programs: latex and imagemagick." :image-input-type "pdf" :image-output-type "png" :image-size-adjust
          (1.0 . 1.0)
          :latex-compiler
          ("pdflatex -interaction nonstopmode -output-directory %o %f")
```

Where the `luamagick`-part is from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41625195). But the error message remains. So how can I tell org-msg to use Lualatex instead of normal Latex? Alternatively, how can I configure org-msg to not use my custom library while leaving it as a default for normal org-mode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the message

```
Please adjust 'imagemagick' part of `org-preview-latex-process-alist'
```

means that in the `imagemagick` part of the list `org-preview-latex-process-alist`, you need to change `"pdflatex -interaction nonstopmode -output-directory %o %f"` to `"lualatex -interaction nonstopmode -output-directory %o %f"` . From what you've shown above, you haven't made that change yet. I don't think you need to even do `(setq org-latex-compiler "lualatex")`, because that controls LaTeX *export* (to `.tex` or `.pdf` files).

**EDIT:** As OP points out, `:image-converter ("convert -density %D -trim -antialias %f -quality 100 %O")` is needed for the `imagemagick` entry to work. So while the `lua` fragments need `lualatex` to be added, the resulting image won't be converted into a `.png` without the `:image-converter` command.

Alternatively, you may want to (1) revert everything back to the previous default settings, and (2) add the following:

```
(imagemagick-lua :programs
          ("lualatex" "convert")
          :description "pdf > png" :message "you need to install the programs: lualatex and imagemagick." :image-input-type "pdf" :image-output-type "png" :image-size-adjust
          (1.0 . 1.0)
          :latex-compiler
          ("lualatex -interaction nonstopmode -output-directory %o %f")
          :image-converter ("convert -density %D -trim -antialias %f -quality 100 %O")
```

(**Edited** to add the `image-converter` part, raised in the comments)

to the end of `org-preview-latex-process-alist`, and then do:

```
(setq org-preview-latex-default-process 'imagemagick-lua)
```

If you only need to use `lualatex` in some documents and prefer the regular method in other cases, after adding the above `imagemagick-lua` process, you could then add the following function to your config:

```
(defun my/lua-latex-previews ()
  "Function to set local org-preview-latex process to Imagemagick-lua"
  (interactive)
  (setq-local org-preview-latex-default-process 'image-magick-lua))
```

and just do `M-x my/lua-latex-previews` in the buffers where you need `lualatex`.

Comment: Thanks! I only now came to try it out. It now compiles but after `Creating LaTeX Image` it says
`org-compile-file: No valid command to process "/tmp/orgtexg9hBIc.pdf".  Please adjust `imagemagick-lua' part of `org-preview-latex-process-alist'.` What does it want now?

Comment: I figured it out: the `image-converter` portion was needed. I added `   :image-converter
       ("convert -density %D -trim -antialias %f -quality 100 %O")` from the `imagemagick`-entry and now it works!

Comment: @AlexanderPraehauser Woops, totally missed that part. I'll correct that so that other people won't get stuck if they follow this up. Yes, that should fix the `imagemagick` entry. But your `luamagick` entry should have worked from the start -- although you might have had to do `(setq org-preview-latex-default-process 'luamagick)` or use the `my/lua-latex-previews` function with `'image-magick-lua` changed to `luamagick`.